# error Refused to execute script, strict MIME type checking

Tags: javascript, wordpress

hola buenas tengo un error en la consola del navegador  el segundo codigo tengo puesto en tema hijo en en el function.php   el tercero en el archivo main js del tema  hijo y el tercero en el header

```
eldiariodemof.com/:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://eldiariodemof.com/diario/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

````
$ (document).ready(function({
    console.log ("ready");

});
```

function my_register_script_method () {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js');
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
````

Comment: ¿Que plataforma estás usando? Nginx, Apache?......

Comment: @H.Díaz estoy usando lite speed